# returning value from page method in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pagemethods

I have a page method which is doing some complicated validation on server side.
I have a button to validate.
javascript code is below:

```
function resultOfValidation(result);
{
    return result;
}

function IsValidDate()
{
    PageMethods.ComplicatedValidation(resultOfValidation);
}
```

C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool ComplicatedValidation()
{
    return true;
}
```

but I want to do like

```
function IsDateTimeAvailable()
{
    var result= PageMethods.ComplicatedValidation();
}
```

As per my knowledge, it is not possible. If you have any alternative,
then please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two last parameters for webmethod on client side are success and error callbacks. You can use them. reuturn value is passed to those functions like an argument.

Comment: I need return value in the same block, where i am invoking the method.

Comment: @SanjayGupta in this case you must call it syncrhonously. Take a look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/03/06/calling-web-service-methods-synchronously-in-asp-net-ajax.aspx) article

Comment: Thanks. Is the above example possible without web service class.

Comment: Yes. That is just a wrapper for XMLHTTPRequest, so you may do that in pure JS or take any other library to call your webservice method

Answer (score 3):

[More...](http://forums.asp.net/t/1188694.aspx)

```
function GetValue() 
{ 
    return PageMethods.GetValueFromServer( 
     function(result) 
       { 
          // The result that is returned from server 
          //Now do what ever you would like to do. 
       }
    ); 
}
```

Comment: I have to do nothing with the value inside the function.

Comment: Suppose I have a button and want to validate before postback.

Comment: btn1.OnClientClick="return IsDateTimeAvailable()"

Comment: @SanjayGupta - result value is retunr value of the function called onserver side that you can check on link

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
           var secuencias = new String;
           jQuery("#add_note").click(function() {

                                                    $.ajax({
                                                    type: "POST",
                                                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Paginas/EscuchadorAlertas.aspx/ConsultarAlertas") %>',
                                                    data: "{}",
                                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                                    dataType: "json",
                                                    async: false,
                                                    success: function(msg) {
                                                        secuencias = msg.d;
                                                    },
                                                    error: function() {
                                                        alert("error");
                                                   }
                                                   });
                                                });
```

As you can see inside the variable secuencia is stored the value of de function ConsultarAlertas which is a PageMethods function that just return a String.